# Quais os equivalentes para "fazenda", "sítio", "chácara" e "rancho" em ptPT?

Tags: vocabulário, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas

Todas se referem a propriedades rurais e a principal diferença entre elas são as dimensões. Todas têm geralmente uma ou mais casas, para uso ocasional, temporário ou contínuo.

- Um rancho é uma pequena propriedade rural, bem simples, onde moram pessoas do campo.
- Uma "chácara" é uma pequena propriedade, de até cinco mil metros quadrados segundo alguns, próxima a uma cidade. Pode ser uma propriedade usada apenas para passar o final de semana.
- Já um "sítio" tem dimensões maiores, podendo chegar a 20 hectares e geralmente fica mais distante da cidade. Podem ser simples e rústicos, mas também podem ser luxuosos, com piscinas, quadras de tênis, campo de golfe, sauna, etc.
- Uma fazenda é uma grande propriedade, chegando algumas vezes a 100.000 hectares em algumas regiões. As fazendas são geralmente destinadas à agricultura e à pecuária, e sempre dispõem de várias moradias para aqueles que lá trabalham.

fontes:

[Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADtio)

[Canal Rural](http://www.canalrural.com.br/noticias/jornal-da-pecuaria/diferenca-entre-chacara-sitio-rancho-fazenda-uma-questao-cultural-26527)

Comment: O rancho pode ser só a casa ou inclui necessariamente terra em volta que pertence à casa ou se destina a ser usada pelos habitantes da casa? Eu interpretei como sendo a segunda, mas parece-me que o @Jorge interpretou como sendo a primeira.

Comment: @Jacinto isso mesmo interpretei como uma casa no meio rural onde mora pessoas do campo. Como diz o Centaurus na descrição.

Comment: Mas é quase de certeza a segunda: "Todas [de rancho a fazenda] referem-se a propriedades rurais e a principal diferença entre elas são as dimensões. Todas têm geralmente uma ou mais casas..." O que pode ter uma ou mais casas é a terra.

Comment: Rancho é a propriedade; o terreno e a morada.  Caso não exista nenhuma contrução, é simplesmente um terreno e não um rancho.

Comment: @JorgeB e Centaurus: Precisamos de um esclarecimento adicional. Eu e o Jorge concordamos que qualquer das casas [neste mapa](https://www.google.pt/maps/@39.1388884,-9.1767569,396m/data=!3m1!1e3) e [neste outro](https://www.google.pt/maps/@41.7590919,-8.1991242,138m/data=!3m1!1e3) e também [neste](https://www.google.pt/maps/@41.6155743,-8.5000442,365m/data=!3m1!1e3) é uma *casa na aldeia*. Agora discordamos é se elas poderiam ser consideradas *chácaras*. Creio que *rancho* está fora de quesão. Podes esclarecer-nos?

Comment: @Jacinto Pois eu acho que seria mesmo um rancho. O Chácara identifica-se mais com uma *casa de campo* (de férias) com 5 mil metros quadrados. Uma casa na aldeia como se vê no mapa é um rancho. Mas se o Centaurus puder esclarecer, melhor.

Comment: Pergunto-me se tu viste os links na pergunta: tudo aquilo são originalmente explorações agrícolas, embora algumas se tenham convertido para fins turísticos. Também me parece que não viste _rancho_ na wikipedia (o link da pergunta tem links para as coisas todas): é descrito como habitação rudimentar para trabalhadores longe da casa principal

Comment: @Jacinto e Jorge B   As fotos mostram casas com quintal ou com jardim.  A segunda foto parece o que chamaríamos de "um condomínio de casas".  Mas não vejo nada que se pareça com uma chácara.

Comment: Aqui está um [link](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=ch%C3%A1cara&safe=off&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source%3F%7D&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIjNahmbmxyAIVxv0eCh1Rqwvv&biw=1920&bih=947#imgrc=_) para uma página com fotos de chácaras, sítios e fazendas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um propriedade do tipo de uma [*fazenda*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fazenda) brasileira seria no Alentejo uma herdade e no resto de Portugal uma quinta. E com a ajuda do conhecimento local,  *sítio* corresponderá a *quinta* ou *granja* (conceitos muito elásticos); e uma *chácara* a um *casal*. E *rancho* corresponde quanto muito a *casal*. Mas isto são tudo instituições moldadas pelas histórias dos respetivos países e até regiões, e as equivalências são provavelmente imperfeitas. Portanto eu preferiria chamar a cada propriedade o nome que faz parte da sua história: não chamaria *quinta* a uma herdade alentejana, nem *herdade* a uma fazenda brasileira, nem *fazenda* a um quinta nas margens do rio Douro.

Embora *fazenda* no caso da quinta não fosse completamente despropositado porque [**fazenda** pode designar em Portuga](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/fazenda) simplesmente um terreno cultivado. Os agricultores tipicamente [vivem numa aldeia e cultivam os seus terrenos espalhadas em volta](https://www.google.pt/maps/@39.1376961,-9.1760347,1212m/data=!3m1!1e3). Na zona onde cresci, a maioria dos terrenos tinham entre meio e dois hectares e distavam até um ou dois quilómetros da aldeia. Há aldeias mais ou menos de dois em dois quilómetros.

Por vezes, uma família decide construir e mudar-se para uma casa num dos seus terrenos fora da aldeia. A casa e o terreno passam a chamar-se [**casal**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/casal). Por vezes há casais próximos uns dos outros; os filhos das primeiras famílias crescem e constroem casas para si ao lado da dos pais, e forma-se outra aldeia, tipicamente com nomes como Casais de Santo António, Casais Brancos, etc. Não me parece que *casal* seja equivalente a *rancho*: a casa é normal como as da aldeia, e atualmente tem todas as comodidades modernas. O conceito brasileiro mais próximo talvez seja *chácara*. Talvez a caraterística distintiva é que é uma família que explora a sua terra tipicamente sem recurso a trabalhadores contratados. *Casal* vem no Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa e é usado na zona onde cresci, uns 50 km a norte de Lisboa, com este significado. Não sei se o é em todo país, nomeadamente no noroeste, onde a população rural tende mais do que no resto do país a viver no que eu chamaria casais. A única indicação que encontrei de que *casal* tem aí o mesmo significado é a existências de várias quintas com nomes como Quinta do Casal disto ou daquilo, o que sugere que um terreno foi primeiro considerado um casal, e depois adquiriu o estatuto de quinta.

Uma [**quinta**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/quinta) pode ser pouco mais que um casal, mas há quintas que são muito mais, suficientemente grandes para empregarem vários trabalhadores assalariados, e até permitir ao proprietário não trabalhar na sua exploração. Neste caso terá tipicamente casas para pelo menos alguns dos trabalhadores, e a casa do proprietário poderá ir até a um pequeno palacete. Depois há a [**granja**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/granja), que é o mesmo que quinta, mas é menos usado. *Quinta* é também usado para designar uma propriedade de lazer com casa rodeada de um grande jardim ou parque mas sem qualquer atividade agrícola. [A casa pode chegar a isto](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quinta_da_Regaleira.jpg?uselang=pt). Atualmente a palavra *quinta* está ser aproveitada pelo marketing para praticamente qualquer casa com um bocadito de terreno.

A [**herdade**](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/herdade) é muito maior que a quinta. Tipicamente de uma centena a milhares de hectares. A maior de que tenho conhecimento tem quinze mil hectares. Algumas chegam ou chegaram a incluir uma aldeia com escola primária. *Herdade* é um nome usado só para propriedades no Alentejo e sul do Ribatejo, onde as propriedades são maiores e a densidade populacional menor que no resto do país. Portanto não sei se a distinção entre algumas *quintas* maiores e *herdade* não é meramente regional. Não sei se *quinta* é comumente usado no Alentejo. Ao palacete do proprietário e construções próximas chama-se [**monte**](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/monte), e por vezes usa-se *monte* para designar a propriedade toda.

Comment: Uma "herdade" certamente seria chamada de "fazenda" aqui no Brasil. As maiores quintas seriam também "fazendas".  Acredito que as menores quintas seriam sítios e os casais seriam chácaras.  Mas aqui no Brasil nem sempre a nomenclatura é respeitada.  Frequentemente dizem "comprei um sítio em Itaipava" e, na verdade, trata-se de uma chácara pequena.  Ou então "Vou passar as férias na fazenda do meu tio", e trata-se de um sítio.

Comment: *Quinta* em Portugal é um conceito muito elástico. Por isso admiti que houvessem chácaras parecidas com as nossas quintas, mas teríamos que ignorar o limite dos 5.000 m2. Mesmo os casais tendem a ser maiores que isso, e têm por referência uma aldeia e não uma cidade. (Eu ia à matança do porco no casal da minha ti Marilena, separado da minha aldeia por uns 500m de pomares e vinhas). Mas revi o texto de acordo com a informação local.

Comment: Nunca tinha ouvido falar em *casal* sequer. Aqui no norte usa-se *casa de campo* ou *casa no campo.*.

Comment: Mesmo aqui em baixo, *casal* possivelmente só é conhecido do pessoal com raízes rurais. Imagino que na tua zona tenha existido pelo menos no passado: há quintas com o nome de *Casal* disto e daquilo. Poderá também ter designado [uma parte duma quinta com casa](http://www.casalgarcia.com/pt/historia/). Agora para mim *casa de campo* ou *casa no campo* é uma casa. Pode ou não ter terreno próprio. Vê os comentários à pergunta. Todos aqueles termos designam terrenos, geralmente, não obrigatoriamente, com um casa, não simplesmente uma casa. *Casa de campo* sugere-me uma casa de férias no campo.

Comment: @JorgeB. Vou perguntar aqui ao pessoal se sabe o que é um casal. Vem no dicionário, mas nem eu me lembrei disso ao princípio.

Comment: @Jacinto sim existem "quintas" como nome "casal". Mas  não sei se se encaixam bem na hipótese "Chácara". Os meus dois primeiros exemplos são um bocado abrangentes mas foi o mais próximo que consegui arranjar. A maioria das vezes é tudo uma "quinta" por aqui.

Comment: Quando me dizem que têm uma *casa de campo* eu fico a achar que tem uma casa com terreno mas com o propósito de passar férias. Quando me dizem que têm uma *casa na aldeia* ou *casa no campo* faz-me lembrar uma casa normal com terreno. Quando me dizem que têm uma *quinta* fico com a ideia de uma grande casa com um grande terreno onde se cultivam variadas coisas e/ou animais. As *herdades* fazem-me lembrar daquelas "quintas" gigantescas do Alentejo.

Comment: No norte também há «casal». Mas eu não sabia o que significava, apesar de conhecer bastantes "casal do corvo" ou "casal da bouça" ou "casal da cavadinha"; nunca tinha pensado nisto.

Comment: @ANeves Eu acabei de ler *Os Fidalgos da Casa Mourisca* do Júlio Dinis, cuja ação se passa algures entre Douro e Minho, e há referências a casais que são partes de propriedades senhoriais maiores, que estão entregues a uma família e têm uma casa.

Comment: @ANeves e Jacinto é verdade que há essas referências, mas quem as usa? Aqui costuma-se dizer "O João tem uma quinta, a quinta casal do corvo".

Answer (score 5):

Em Português de Portugal o mais próximo das definições que consigo arranjar é:

- **Casa no campo**/**Casa na [aldeia](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/aldeia)**/**Casa rural**

  Claro que estas opções, dependendo do contexto, podem ter outros significados. Mas as três indicam, **normalmente**, uma casa com terreno fora da cidade. Dificilmente uma *casa na aldeia* não tem terreno, mas pode acontecer.

  *- Ele vive numa casa na aldeia no meio do nada, e não na cidade*

  *- Ele tem uma casa no campo e eu tenho na cidade.*
- [**Casa de campo**](http://www.casasnocampo.net/PT/)

  Propriedade usada para passar fins de semanas, dá sempre a ideia de ter terreno associado. Neste caso dá a ideia que é uma pessoa com algum dinheiro para ter uma casa de campo. É o equivalente a ter uma casa na praia.

  *- Eu tenho uma casa de campo, no norte, que é uma maravilha para passar uns fins de semana.*
- [**Quinta**](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/quinta)

  **Com certeza é a mais usada para as 2 últimas opções.**
   Temos quintas para fazer casamentos e todo o tipo de festas, quintas luxuosas das pessoas mais abastadas e quintas de gente mais pobre também onde o principal negocio é a agricultura, cada vez menos essas.

  > ### quin·ta
  >
  > 1. Terreno de semeadura com horta e árvores, murado ou cercado de sebes, e que tem geralmente casa de habitação.
  > 2. Casa de campo.
  >
  > "quinta", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
  >   2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/quinta [consultado em
  >   02-10-2015].
  >    **
- [**Herdade**](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/herdade)

  Mais usada no sul de Portugal, mas dá sempre a ideia de ter uma dimensão maior do que uma quinta, talvez porque, no sul as propriedade são muito maiores.

  > ### her·da·de
  >
  > Grande propriedade rústica geralmente composta de montado e terras de
  >   semeadura; quinta.
  >
  > "herdade", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
  >   2008-2013, http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/herdade [consultado em
  >   02-10-2015].

Comment: Uma _casa na aldeia no meio do nada?_ Uma casa na aldeia está junto a outras casas! Não corresponde a nenhuma das coisas na pergunta. E casa rural parece-me muito ambíguo.

Comment: @Jacinto foi o mais próximo que consegui arranjar. Bem sei que são as duas um bocado ambíguas, mas quando eu me quero referir a *uma pequena propriedade rural, bem simples, onde moram pessoas do campo.* costumo usar uma casa na aldeia ou uma casa rural. Uma casa na aldeia não tem de ter casas por perto. Eu tenho uma casa na aldeia que não tem casas no raio de 500 metros. Só terrenos agrícolas.

Comment: Na maior parte do país, não se pode dizer que uma casa na aldeia tenha terreno: [vê esta aldeia ou outras em redor](https://www.google.pt/maps/@39.1388884,-9.1767569,396m/data=!3m1!1e3): muitas nem jardim têm. Mesmo no noroeste [vê esta aldeia](https://www.google.pt/maps/@41.7590919,-8.1991242,138m/data=!3m1!1e3) ou [esta outra](https://www.google.pt/maps/@41.6155743,-8.5000442,365m/data=!3m1!1e3). Há muitas que só têm um bcadinho de relavado; outras nem isso.

Comment: @Jacinto nesses exemplos que me deste vê as fotos abaixo. Repara que quase todas as casas das fotos têm terreno. Ora repara bem.

Comment: @Jacinto estás a ser literal demais. Pergunta à maioria das pessoas se *uma casa na aldeia* não lhe faz lembrar uma casa com terreno por mais pequeno que seja esse terreno.

Comment: @Jacinto concordo com o Jorge que estás a ser literal demais. Na minha experiência, numa aldeia há espaço para se poder ter um terreno em volta da casa, e por isso muitas das casas **têm** de facto um terreno em volta, maior ou menor. (Serão diferenças norte-sul?) Algumas não, outras sim. Podendo, têm-no; e normalmente podem, porque não há a falta de espaço que há nas cidades e vilas. Depois, há tipicamente casas mais fora do núcleo da aldeia, que têm progressivamente *mais e mais terreno*. Normalmente espalhadas ao longo da estrada que atravessa pela aldeia.

Comment: Um exemplo de satélite: https://www.google.pt/maps/place/Orbac%C3%A9m/@41.8015744,-8.7737091,665m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0xd25b93737d2f7b5:0x500ebbde4910ea0

Comment: @ANeves Eu acho que tu e o Jorge não chegaram a compreender o que é uma chácara, rancho, etc. Vê o vídeo na pergunta: estes termos designam propriedades que podem ir de 1 a 5, 10, 50, centenas de hectares. É claro que tu podes ter, por exemplo, uma casa inserida num hectare de terreno na orla duma aldeia, e dizeres indiferentemente  que tens uma casa na aldeia ou tens uma quinta. Mas *quinta* e *casa na aldeia* não são sinónimos: uma quinta a 5km da aldeia mais próxima não é uma casa na aldeia, e uma casa sem terreno ou só com um pequeno jardim, como há muitas, não é uma quinta.

Comment: @ANeves Dizendo de outro modo, terreno em volta da casa não faz parte da definição de *casa  na aldeia*. Vê também os comentários à pergunta. Há um meu com fotos de aldeias, e um comentário do Centaurus mais abaixo confirmando que não vê nessas fotos «nada que que se pareça com uma chácara».

Comment: @Jacinto repara que eu fiz distinção de casa **no** campo e casa **de** campo. Casa no campo é equivalente a casa na aldeia, não tem obrigatoriamente terreno, mas com eu escrevi, **normalmente** é uma casa com terreno.

Comment: @Jacinto fiz umas edições para esclarecer melhor, vê o que achas.